# Need MAC Laptop configuration for start working on Xcode, iPhone apps and pushing to AppStore

Tags: ios, macos

I would like to buy a mac laptop range(55,000 INR - 75,000INR). I need to develop the apps and to submit them to Appstore. Could you please suggest me the best laptop.

I am looking into the Apple MD101HN/A Macbook Pro MD101HN/A Core i5 - (4 GB DDR3/500 GB HDD/Mac OS) Notebook. Will it be good for developing the applications.

Comment: You'll most likely be happy with any modern macbook with enough memory (aka as much as possible). As for which one is "best", that's rather opinion based so may not be a good question for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pretty much any MacBook and above. All of them will deliver capability to develop IOS apps.

Your choice is fine, although I do suggest upgrading it to SSD (preferably Intel) and add extra RAM (8Gb+) (Kingston)

Intel SSD 530 Series http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/solid-state-drives/consumer-family.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments.